# Initialize a static local variable to a value unknown during compilation

Tags: c++, c, compilation, static-variables

In the C language, in order to initialize a static local variable to a value unknown during compilation, I would normally do something like this (for example):

```
void func()
{
    static int var = INVALID_VALUE;
    if (var == INVALID_VALUE)
        var = some_other_func();
    ...
}
```

In the C++ language, I can simply do:

```
void func()
{
    static int i = some_other_func();
    ...
}
```

The only way (that I can think of) for a C++ compiler to resolve it properly, is by replacing this code with a mechanism similar to the C example above.

But how would the compiler determine a "proper" invalid value? Or is there another way which I haven't taken into consideration?

Thanks

---

**Clarification:**

`INVALID_VALUE` is a value which function `some_other_func` never returns.

It is used in order to ensure that this function is never invoked more than once.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What does `INVALID_VALUE` represent? And what's the point of it?

Comment: @JosephMansfield: I think, OP means some value `some_other_func` never returns to check if `var` has been assigned a return value of that function.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: A value which I consider invalid, and that I know `some_other_func` will never return (for example, if it was a pointer, then I would normally use `NULL`).

Comment: @mafso: Thank you for making my point clearer :)

Comment: I was 30sec too quick… :)

Comment: @mafso: And I too slow. Will add it to the question... Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure that's the same question. Edit: Maybe not. It's similar.

Comment: The compiler does not need an invalid value, a flag 'initialized' will do it, even for an object with a constructor.

Comment: @JosephMansfield That question answers the OP question

Comment: @Mansuro It does, but it's not the same question. The answer was in the question of that question.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Thanks. I actually feel kinda stupid asking this question in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will not generate code to do it based on its value but on a thread safe flag that ensure that the code is only executed once.

Something like that:

```
void func()
{
    static int i;
    static bool i_initialized;
    if (!i_initialized) {
      i = some_other_func();
      i_initialized = true;
    }
}
```

Except that generally it is not a bool but a thread safe way of testing it.

Comment: Thank you. It's pretty much the same answer as the one given by @Dieter Lücking in one of the comments above (which makes me feel kinda stupid asking this question in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

According to code seen by disassembling and debugging the g++ compiled code, there is a hidden variable that is initialized to 0 and when the initialization is run it is set to 1.
So the next time the initialization code isn't executed.